# How to Take both ID and Value in click function

Tags: node.js, angular

select the option from the drop down. I need selected both Id and Value. Im using angular material

```
select  (click)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="1">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: There no IDs in your code.

Comment: @Jayanthi Kindly add workable and understandable code. Your code doesn't match your question.

Comment: I think Jayanthi wants to understand the reactive form for select dropdown

Comment: Why is Wednesday called `1`, but others have names?

Comment: @jayanthi, you always can use `(click)="selectChangeHander($event,'myId',anotherVariable)`. BTW, if you want, you can binding a variable in your .ts with the select use `[(ngModel)]' (see [docs](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#ngModel) or [reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have placed `click` event instead of change, nextup you can capture values selected via reactive form very easily, I suggest you use reactive form that will help,

your HTML should look like this

```
<select [formControl]="selectDropDownValue">
  <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
  <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="1">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>`enter code here`
</select>
```

now change your component to look like this,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'stackoverflow-examples';
  
  selectDropDownValue: FormControl;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.selectDropDownValue = new FormControl('Monday');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectDropDownValue.valueChanges.subscribe(
      chng => {
        console.log('The changed value is :', chng);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

after this change, you can easily capture all the changed values in the subscription,

If you wish to change the default value you just need to change the value of form control in the .ts file and you should be good, give it a go and let me know how you go . . ...